# Weather API, Python or JavaScript

Tags: python, django, weather-api

I am trying to get weather API working. But how can I just get the C° and weather icon; nothing else?

Comment: Loads of examples here - https://github.com/pjkundert/python-weather-api/tree/master/examples

Comment: @CalvinCheng, does pywapi come in python built-in?  how do i get the weather icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have installed [pywapi](http://code.google.com/p/python-weather-api/) with pip, open a ipython shell and explore what `pywapi` can do. Here's an example which actually gives you what you want:-

```
In [1]: import pywapi

In [2]: pywapi.
pywapi.GOOGLE_CITIES_URL                   pywapi.YAHOO_WEATHER_URL                   pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com        pywapi.urlopen
pywapi.GOOGLE_COUNTRIES_URL                pywapi.getText                             pywapi.get_weather_from_yahoo              pywapi.wind_beaufort_scale
pywapi.NOAA_WEATHER_URL                    pywapi.get_cities_from_google              pywapi.minidom                             pywapi.wind_direction
pywapi.URLError                            pywapi.get_countries_from_google           pywapi.quote                               pywapi.xml_get_attrs
pywapi.WEATHER_COM_URL                     pywapi.get_everything_from_yahoo           pywapi.re                                  pywapi.xml_get_ns_yahoo_tag
pywapi.YAHOO_WEATHER_NS                    pywapi.get_weather_from_noaa               pywapi.sys                                 pywapi.yield_all_country_city_codes_yahoo

In [2]: pywapi.get_weather_from_yahoo?
Type:       function
String Form:<function get_weather_from_yahoo at 0x10daeb9b0>
File:       /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myweather/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pywapi.py
Definition: pywapi.get_weather_from_yahoo(location_id, units='metric')
Docstring:
Fetches weather report from Yahoo! Weather

Parameters:
  location_id: A five digit US zip code or location ID. To find your location ID,
  browse or search for your city from the Yahoo! Weather home page (http://weather.yahoo.com/)
  The weather ID is in the URL for the forecast page for that city. You can also get
  the location ID by entering your zip code on the home page. For example, if you
  search for Los Angeles on the Weather home page, the forecast page for that city
  is http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0638.html. The location ID is USCA0638.

  units: type of units. 'metric' for metric and '' for non-metric
  Note that choosing metric units changes all the weather units to metric,
  for example, wind speed will be reported as kilometers per hour and
  barometric pressure as millibars.

Returns:
  weather_data: a dictionary of weather data that exists in XML feed.
  See http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#channel

In [3]: pywapi.get_weather_from_yahoo('USCA0638')
Out[3]:
{'astronomy': {'sunrise': u'6:16 am', 'sunset': u'7:28 pm'},
 'atmosphere': {'humidity': u'67',
  'pressure': u'1013.7',
  'rising': u'1',
  'visibility': u'16.09'},
 'condition': {'code': u'33',
  'date': u'Sat, 20 Apr 2013 9:46 pm PDT',
  'temp': u'18',
  'text': u'Fair',
  'title': u'Conditions for Los Angeles, CA at 9:46 pm PDT'},
 'forecasts': [{'code': u'31',
   'date': u'20 Apr 2013',
   'day': u'Sat',
   'high': u'26',
   'low': u'15',
   'text': u'Clear'},
  {'code': u'32',
   'date': u'21 Apr 2013',
   'day': u'Sun',
   'high': u'26',
   'low': u'14',
   'text': u'Sunny'},
  {'code': u'34',
   'date': u'22 Apr 2013',
   'day': u'Mon',
   'high': u'22',
   'low': u'13',
   'text': u'Mostly Sunny'},
  {'code': u'30',
   'date': u'23 Apr 2013',
   'day': u'Tue',
   'high': u'21',
   'low': u'14',
   'text': u'Partly Cloudy'},
  {'code': u'30',
   'date': u'24 Apr 2013',
   'day': u'Wed',
   'high': u'19',
   'low': u'13',
   'text': u'Partly Cloudy'}],
 'geo': {'lat': u'34.05', 'long': u'-118.23'},
 'html_description': u'\n[![][5]][5]<br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nFair, 18 C<BR />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />\nSat - Clear. High: 26 Low: 15<br />\nSun - Sunny. High: 26 Low: 14<br />\nMon - Mostly Sunny. High: 22 Low: 13<br />\nTue - Partly Cloudy. High: 21 Low: 14<br />\nWed - Partly Cloudy. High: 19 Low: 13<br />\n<br />\n<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Los_Angeles__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0638_c.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>\n(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>\n',
 'link': u'http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Los_Angeles__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0638_c.html',
 'location': {'city': u'Los Angeles', 'country': u'US', 'region': u'CA'},
 'title': u'Yahoo! Weather - Los Angeles, CA',
 'units': {'distance': u'km',
  'pressure': u'mb',
  'speed': u'km/h',
  'temperature': u'C'},
 'wind': {'chill': u'18', 'direction': u'0', 'speed': u'0'}}
```

As you can see in the results, you can get the weather icon in `html_description` (http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/33.gif) and the `temp`.  Since the results returned to you is everything, you will need to extract/access it like you would do with a python dictionary.

**UPDATE**

1. Go to http://weather.yahoo.com/ and type in your zip code (or your city).
2. If there is more than one choice, pick the one you want.
3. Locate the link "extended forecast" under "6-10 day" column. Click it.
4. Look at the URL address bar and the numbers there is your city's zip code.

**ALL CITY CODE**

Here's the function that helps you get all country, city codes

```
In [4]: pywapi.yield_all_country_city_codes_yahoo?
Type:       function
String Form:<function yield_all_country_city_codes_yahoo at 0x10daebaa0>
File:       /Users/calvin/.virtualenvs/myweather/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pywapi.py
Definition: pywapi.yield_all_country_city_codes_yahoo(country_code, cities)
Docstring:
Yield all cities codes for a specific country.

Parameters:
  country_code: A four letter code of the necessary country. For example 'GMXX' or 'FRXX'.
  cities: The number of cities to yield

Returns:
  country_city_codes: A generator containing the city codes
```

Comment: very nice, let me try this.

Comment: can I also get data from yahoo using german zip code for german city?

Comment: I installed pywapi and put it in settings.py, but once i import in my views.py, it is showing me error saying that pywapi unresolved import. what can be the problem?

Comment: `settings.py` and `views.py`? `pywapi` isn't a django app. Once you have installed it in your `virtualenv` or your global site-packages if you are not using `virtualenv`, it will be available in your `views.py`. (You shouldn't place it in `settings.py` because it is not a django app`). If you `views.py` cannot import it, it means that you have set your python paths wrongly.

Comment: oh, okay. I see there is only egg file in sitepackages, is that okay, or should there be also a folder of pywapi?

Comment: only an egg should be fine. for the city code, see my updated explanation above.

Comment: cool thanks. but one more question. I want to get data dynamically and not for fixed city name. is this also possible with yahoo?

Comment: If you are experimenting with `pywapi` in your ipython shell, you might have noticed - `pywapi.yield_all_country_city_codes_yahoo`  Try it out and see if that gives you a whole list of country city codes that yahoo provides and hence, you are able to dynamically decide which city code you want to retrieve weather data from.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28585/discussion-between-doniyor-and-calvin-cheng)

Comment: i dont see that function in the shell, can you please show me where? :(

Comment: Are you using ipython? If you are, after you have typed `import pywapi`, in the next line, type `pywapi.` and hit tab.

Comment: yeah,but i dont know what parameter it takes, :(. I am only getting this.``<function yield_all_country_city_codes_yahoo at 0x00000000031F4BA8>``

Comment: I type in the python shell ``pywapi.yield_all_country_codes_yahoo`` and i am getting that thing above again

Comment: Notice the `?` behind. This is a useful iPython trick that would help you introspect new libraries that you are not familiar with.

Comment: it saying: ``?`` is invalid syntax. :(

Comment: You are not using ipython shell. You are using plain python shell.

Comment: yeah, thats why i think, i am installing ipython now. but in views, it should work then,

Answer (score 2):

You can use Metwit [weather api](http://metwit.com/developers/).
If you can implement them client-side: 200 request/day (ip based throttling) no authentication required. Worldwide coverage, JSON and REST compliant. You can register for extra API calls for free and if you still need it to call them server side the basic plan is pretty cheap.

Here a little example in jQuery: http://jsbin.com/isukam/1 that use our [weather resource](http://metwit.com/developers/docs/resources/weather/).

Full disclosure: I own this sweet piece of API.

Comment: wow, very cool. it is soo light and easy to use. thanks for mentioning, may be i am taking this version